# Using Partition by in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following code to read data from sql:

```
var subs = await _context.Subs
                .Include(s => s.SubsHistories)
                .Include(s => s.App)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.OwnerHistories)
                .Include(s => s.App)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.SubmitterHistories))
                .ToListAsync();
```

This works fine however this returns a large amount of data especially the last two joins (OwnerHistories and SubmitterHistories). All I need from the last 2 joins is the latest modified row from OwnerHistories and SubmitterHistories for each App. Here is the updated SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Subs] AS [s0]
INNER JOIN [SubsHistories] AS [s1] ON [s0].[Id] = [s1].[SubId]
INNER JOIN
(  -- get only latest owner history
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
    FROM OwnerHistories
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY AppId ORDER BY ODate DESC)
) AS [baba] ON [baba].[AppId] = [s0].AppId
INNER JOIN 
(  -- get only latest submitter history
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
    FROM SubmitterHistories
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY AppId ORDER BY SDate DESC)
) AS [dada] ON [dada].[AppId] = [s0].AppId
```

How do I perform this using using EF?

UPDATE: Tried the solution below but it looks it is supported for EFCore5+. Is there another way - maybe split this to multiple selects instead of using multiple includes? Example:

```
var subs1 = await _context.Subs.Include(s => s.SubsHistories);
var subs2 = await _context.Subs.Include(s => s.App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filtered includes.

Let's imagine your entities have a `UpdatedOn` field which we can use for sorting in chronological order.

```
var subs = await _context.Subs
                .Include(s => s.SubsHistories)
                .Include(s => s.App)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.OwnerHistories.OrderByDescending(h => h.UpdatedOn).Take(1))
                .Include(s => s.App)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.SubmitterHistories.OrderByDescending(h => h.UpdatedOn).Take(1))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! This SubmitterHistories).OrderByDescending should be SubmitterHistories.OrderByDescending correct? remove ')'

Comment: I see 'Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid' on trying the above query. What am I missing?

Comment: I also notice this error: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`

Comment: This only works on EF 5+, you might not be on it. If you are not then there's no way to achieve what you want through `Include()` calls.

Comment: I see - is there a way to use the sql query in the code to perform your above solution? Please let me know!

Comment: I use EF 3.1.1. Is there an alternate way to solve this in 3.1.1?

Comment: in your above solution, .OwnerHistories does this return latest row for each sub?