# Latest modified row for each item

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a sql table containing multiple rows with a memberid and lastmodified date. I need to get latest modified row for each member id. This is what I have tried in EFCore 3.1.1:

```
var a = context.Members
    .Include(m => m.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.LastModifiedDate)
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

and it gives error: ***Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid***

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I tried this as well that didn't work either:

```
 var a = context.Histories
              .GroupBy(h => h.MemberId)
              .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastModifiedDate).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

```
The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (o.MemberId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: History
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.LastModifiedDate)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: You're confusing `.Include` with `.Where`

Comment: Please clarify if by "EF 3+" you're referring to Entity Framework 3.x (released a decade ago...) or Entity Framework Core 3+?

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0):

While newer versions of EF Core do support some filtering via adding `Where` clauses, it's best to think of entities as a "complete" or "complete-able" representation of your data state. You either use the complete state of data, or you project to get the details you want.

For example, if you just want the last modified date for each member:

```
var lastModifiedDetails = context.Members
    .Select(m => new 
    { 
        m.MemberId,
        LastModifiedDate = m.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.LastModifiedDate)
            .Select(h => h.LastModifiedDate)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();
```

This would give you a collection containing the MemberId and it's LastModifiedDate.

Alternatively, if you want the complete member and a quick reference to the last modified date:

```
var memberDetails = context.Members
    .Select(m => new 
    { 
        Member = m,
        LastModifiedHistory = m.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.LastModifiedDate)
            .FirstOrDefault()
   }).ToList();
```

Here instead of trying to get the last modified date or the latest history through a Member entity, you get a set of anonymous types that project down that detail. You iterate through that collection and can get the applicable history and/or modified date for the associated Member.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try it out. Could you also please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977078/using-partition-by-in-entity-framework if possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use a similar approach so rather than eager loading the history records using `Include`, use `Select` to fetch the top level entity then selecting the newest historical records or dates using the same approach as above. You should also plan for/champion the project keeping migrating to .Net 6 / EF Core 6 and beyond. The .Net landscape has changed where particular versions are only supported for 18-36 months. Migrating may seem like a pain/expense but it only gets worse the longer it is put off and you can take advantage of new features and performance by setting that expectation.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m a bit confused. Could you please provide a sample code for the same?

Comment: I have a 1) subs table which has sub id and app id (FK), 2) apps table containing app id (PK) and app name 3) histories table which has app id (FK), modified date. By adding this code I believe I could get all apps along with last modified date. How do I add submission id along with that? var lastModifiedDetails = _context.Apps.Select(m => new
                    {
                        m.Id, LastModifiedDate = m.Histories.OrderByDescending(h => h.LastModifiedDate).Select(h => h.LastModifiedDate).FirstOrDefault()}).ToList();